# Android play store Closed testing URL not showing "something went wrong" in play store

Tags: android, testing, google-play

I Want to check application on the closed testing mode.
here are the steps that i follow for the closed testing (ref. video that i follow https://youtu.be/hyRjUbdFHn0 )

1. Create ABB file from the android studios
2. Set necessary details to playstore account (icon, title , desc, policy etc)
3. Upload ABB file under closed testing section
4. Add test users email address
5. Send build for the review
6. After review successfully by the playstore i copy link from the Testes section and send to testing device

on testing device playstore i seen everytime "Something went wrong"

other things i did

- I already clear catch and data on play store app
- Also clear catch of google chrome

is there any steps that i missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my given steps everything was right i just need to set application on the publish mode from the
Setup >> Advance setting >> App availability set to  **Published**